# Maven : How to unpack dependencies in specific order?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

My project is depending on many ZIP resources.

With "maven-dependency-plugin" and its "unpack-dependencies", I kown how to unpack each dependency.

But (for different reasons I cannot explain here), I have to unpack the dependencies in a specific order (*).

Is it possible to unpack in a specific order, or is it possible to manage the dependencies order ?

Thanks,

Xavier

(*) there are some files with the same names, and I have to overwrite some files from one dependency with other from another dependency ....

[EDIT][SOLUTION]

Thanks for answers.

I found a solution with [copy-maven-plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin).

Here is an example of solution for my problem :
https://gist.github.com/4164769

Comment: You might not be able to control the order but you could include/exclude files from certain dependencies see [unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant pom section for the maven-dependency-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

As in most cases with Maven, I think there are several ways to do this, and you'll have to find the most elegant way yourself.  I'll give you an idea of how I'd get started.

First, you can use the [dependency plugin's unpack mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) to unpack a specific set of artifact; you name the artifacts specifically in the configuration of the execution.  It's possible that you can name more than one here and they will be processed in order.  However, if that doesn't work, you can always configure as many executions of this mojo as necessary, and then order those executions in your pom itself, which DOES control ordering.  Note, you can configure the unpack target on a per execution basis too, which may help you.

Another usefull tool that might apply here is the assembly plugin with a custom assembly descriptor.  The assembly, like the unpack mojo discussed above, can be configured to handle specific artifacts, rather than just all of them, and the granularity and ordering of the processing is highly flexible.